# Видны ребра всех полигонов при сглаживании

Tags: c++, opengl

Нарисовал закругленный прямоугольиник, хочу сгладить углы. 
Но сглаживание работает неожиданно. Становятся видны грани всех полигонов, составляющих фигуру(светлые полосы).

```
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему это происходит:

Вы рисуете первый полигон. Допустим у него грань идет ровно посередке пикселя (50% перекрытие). В пиксель будет записано среднее значение между цветом пикселя (допустим белым) и цветом полигона (допустим 100% рыжий). Теперь вы рисуете второй полигон, так же у него грань идет ровно посередке пикселя (50% перекрытие). В пиксель будет так же записано среднее значение между текущим цветом пикселя (которое сейчас 50% рыжий и 50% белый) и цветом полигона (100% рыжий). В итоге у пикселя цвет 75% рыжий и 25% белый - это и есть ваша "видимая" грань.

P.S. Из-за этого у вас также заметно, что верх и низ светлее чем середина.

---

Как нарисовать сглаженный прямоугольник:

- включить аппаратное сглаживание
- рисовать полигон без сглаживания, но поверх него рисовать его контур с `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH)`
- отказаться от полигональной формы и вместо этого рисовать спрайт с текстурой

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю использовать `шейдеры` или как предожили ранее рисовать поверх полигона контур со сглаживанием